# JAVA/ANDROID - How can I generate a NEW random number, without it being identical to the previous random number?

Tags: java, android, random, numbers

I am generating 2 random numbers with `Random random = new Random();` to make a random sum. Code:

```
    int min = 5, max = 20
    randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    randomNum1 = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
```

Then I display the sum like this:

```
    TextView sumText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sumText);
    sumText.setText(randomNum + " + " + randomNum1 + " =");
```

Below the sum is an `EditText`, and then when I enter the answer it checks if the answer is good, and when it's good it repeats all the code above so a new sum is generated. 
However, I still have a problem. Sometimes when the sum is generated it generates the same sum as the old sum. How can I let it generate a NEW sum, without it being identical to the previous sum? I think I should do something with the `while` command but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you specify that a random number cannot have some property, then it is no longer random. Is your question really "how can I generate two random numbers that are not the same"?

Comment: I am generating a random sum that someone can answer, then I check if it's right. And then I want to make a new identical sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Test {

    Random random;
    private int min = 5, max = 20;

    int num1;
    int num2;

    public Test(){
        random = new Random();
        num1 = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        num2 = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
    }

    public int getSum(){
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Test obj) {
        return this.getSum() == obj.getSum();
    }
}
```

// Main class

```
Test t1 = new Test();
Test t2 = new Test();

while(t2.equals(t1)){
    t2 = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a utility class, which can have a unique number generator. Like this,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class RandomNumberGenerator
{
    private int min = 5, max = 20;
    private List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    private Random random = new Random();

    public int getNextRandomNumber() {

        int randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        if(randomList.contains(randomNum)) {
            randomNum = getNextRandomNumber();
        }
        randomList.add(randomNum);
        return randomNum;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // you can use this piece of code anywhere to generate 
        // random numbers using the utility method of RandomNumberGenerator

        RandomNumberGenerator randomNumberGenerator = new RandomNumberGenerator();
        int randomNum = randomNumberGenerator.getNextRandomNumber();
        int randomNum1 = randomNumberGenerator.getNextRandomNumber();

        System.out.println(randomNum);
        System.out.println(randomNum1);



    }
}
```

Comment: It's for android... And I'm a beginner.

Comment: Thats y I wrote that comment in the main function. Classes and objects in android are what is it in java. Only thing you have is resources and manifest as extra. In android also you will be creating classes and you can create instances of those classes and use it. So, whatever is written inside main, is how you can use RandomNumberGenerator. Wherever you want to use it, use it.

Answer (score 0):

That honestly should be simple if you just change it to this:

```
int min = 5, max = 20;
randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
do {
    randomNum1 = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
} while(randomNum == randomNum1);
```

EDIT: You just need to store previous sums, then.

```
List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
randomNum = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
do {
    randomNum1 = random.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
} while(sums.contains(randomNum+randomNum1));
sums.add(randomNum + randomNum1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but you understood my question wrong. `randomNum` and `randomNum1` can be the same. If someone enters the right answer of the sum it generates  `randomNum` and `randomNum1` again and it must be a different sum than then the previous sum generated.